# Is a good practice left an empty interface?

Tags: c#, interface

This time, I'm gonna create a math problems. I plan to have a dictionary where the key is Levels enum {Easy, Medium, Hard} and value should contain some configuration about how to create the problems.

For example:

```
BinaryProblemConfiguration
    + Bound1 : Bound<int>
    + Bound2 : Bound<int>
```

Bound has two properties: min and max.

Others types of problems don't need Bounds, but need other data.

So, I was thinking create a interface called IConfiguration.

```
public interface IConfiguration {}
```

And concrete Configurations should be:

```
public class BinaryProblemConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    public Bound Bound1 {get;set;}
    public Bound Bound2 {get;set;}
}

public class AnotherProblemConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    // other stuff
}
```

The idea is to have a dictionary called ConfigurationLevels. Is this a good practice left the interface empty or means is wrong with my design?

Comment: If you're certain the interface will never have any methods, what purpose does it server? If it just marks a class as being of a certain "type", use an attribute.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern

Comment: Attributes in C# and annotations in Java provide means for metadata, rendering a 'marker interface' obsolete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .NET Framework Design Guidelines calls this a "marker" interface and definitely says that it is a bad idea. They recommned using a custom Attribute instead.

> Avoid using marker interfaces (interfaces with no members).
>
> Custom attributes provide a way to mark a type. For more information
>   about custom attributes, see Writing Custom Attributes. Custom
>   attributes are preferred when you can defer checking for the attribute
>   until the code is executing. If your scenario requires compile-time
>   checking, you cannot comply with this guideline.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229022.aspx

```
public sealed class ConfigurationAttribute : Attribute {

}


[ConfigurationAttribute]
public class AnotherProblemConfiguration : IConfiguration 
{ 
    // other stuff 
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how declare it? Can you show me how would I change it?

Comment: P.S. This rule only applies to professional-grade libraries. If you are hacking something out for yourself or your company you can use a marker interface.

Comment: I knew to create empty interfaces looks strange. Maybe I'm wrong, but it's still show me an error in IConfiguration

Answer (score 2):

Where would you use an instance of `IConfiguration` by itself?  If there is a use case like this:

```
void Something(IConfiguration configuration) { ... }
```

Then yes, its fine.  But with an empty interface, that's going to be an interesting use case.  Offhand, the one that comes to mind is serializing objects, where you know that the object to be serialized via that method must be an IConfiguration, but you don't actually care about what IConfiguration looks like:

```
void SerializeConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration) { ... }
```

Now from a purely functional perspective, this would work just as well with Object, but I think it is a reasonable way of providing a compile-time mechanism for strongly suggesting that someone doesn't serialize anything but a configuration using this method.

Another common usage for these is marker interfaces, where you use reflection to find types that are 'marked' by implementing a common interface.

Comment: I would reword 'interesting' as 'bad'. An empty interface contradicts it's purpose. That's what attributes are for, as Jonathan Alles pointed out.

Comment: Ah, but checking to see if an object has an interface is much faster than checking to see if an object's type has an attribute.

Comment: @diggingforfire I can think of at least one use case where an empty interface is useful...  I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: you mean performance wise? Sounds like micro-optimalization that does not justify the misuse of interfaces to me.

Comment: @ChrisShain I recently wrote a serializer and I used Attributes instead. What's particularly useful with attributes is that I can precache a bunch of information for my serializable types at load time by getting all classes that have the serializable attribute. I'm not sure if this is possible with an interface. Since attributes can also be applied to Properties and Fields, you can also specify what exactly to serialize from an object. This is not possible with an interface unless all your properties' types are implementing the interface which would be really odd

Answer (score 1):

It can definitely be useful to have an interface which extends another interface but adds nothing to it.  For example, one could easily imagine use cases for an `IImmutableEnumerable<T>` which inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, but promises that the sequence of items it returns will never change for any reason.  A routine which needs to have a list of items that isn't going to change could have overloads for `IEnumerable<T>` and `IImmutableEnumerable<T>`.  The first overload could check whether supplied object instance implements `IImmutableEnumerable<T>` and, if not, produce a new immutable list by copying the items in the original; the second overload could simply use the passed-in list directly, since it would be known to implement `IImmutableEnumerable<T>`.

It's somewhat harder to imagine use cases for an interface which doesn't have any members at all.  Such an interface could be used in constraints to allow a routine to accept various types which had no other common base type, but unfortunately class hierarchies which are complex enough to make such a thing conceptually useful make it very difficult to persist objects which meet such constraints.

Comment: Would this change of contract be a violation of [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?

Comment: The interface `IEnumerable<T>` promises that a request for enumeration will yield some sequence. It makes no promise about whether code holding a reference to an implementation can use that reference to modify the sequence, nor does it promise that all future requests for enumeration will yield the same sequence. If `IImmutableEnumerable<T>` (derived from `IEnumerable<T>`) promises that all future enumerations will yield the same sequence, such a promise would not contradict any promise by `IEnumerable<T>`. Note that many implementations of `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: ...could not legitimately implement `IImmutableEnumerable<T>` because they cannot promise that all future enumerations will return the same thing. Note also that no type which implements `IImmutableEnumerable<T>`, nor any type which inherits from one that does, could legitimately offer any means of changing the sequence encapsulated thereby. That many legitimate implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` would not implement `IImmutableEnumerable<T>` is not an LSP violation; derived interfaces are *expected* to impose new requirements on *implementers*--just not on *consumers*.